# import h5py occurrs "Library not loaded" error

Tags: python, macos, pip, hdf5

I can't import h5py on OSX 10.8. There is not `libhdf5.7.dylib` in my `/usr/local/lib`.

```
>>> import h5py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/sudou/.pyenv/versions/anaconda-2.0.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _errors
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/sudou/.pyenv/versions/anaconda-2.0.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_errors.so, 2): Library not loaded: libhdf5.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/sudou/.pyenv/versions/anaconda-2.0.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/h5py/_errors.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I've installed `hdf5` by home brew and might need to downgrade `hdf5`. But, I can not find the way.

```
% ls /usr/local/lib/libhdf*  
/usr/local/lib/libhdf5.9.dylib    /usr/local/lib/libhdf5.settings   /usr/local/lib/libhdf5_hl.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libhdf5.a          /usr/local/lib/libhdf5_hl.9.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libhdf5.dylib      /usr/local/lib/libhdf5_hl.a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try simply running `pip install h5py`.

I did this and was able to `import h5py` in the interpreter without any trouble.

Comment: Yes, this might help - but do it with `-U` flag: `pip install -U h5py`, additionally you can specify location of hdf5: `pip install -U --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I<include_dir>" --global-option="-L<lib_dir>" h5py`. Hope it helps!

Comment: No. It does not work for me. Even after running `pip install --global-option=build_ext --global-option="-I/usr/local/include"`, `import h5py` gives me the same error.